# How to get parent node of element using tinyxml

Tags: c++, parsing, parent-child, tinyxml

Is there a way to get a parent node from a TiXmlElement? For example...

```
TiXmlElement *parent = child->ParentElement( "someName" );
```

If you can't do this in tinyxml, are there any other xml parsers that allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TinyXML's TiXmlElement is derived from TiXMLNode which contains a method called Parent().